# What is the most efficient way to calculate correlation between each pair of a matrix rows in julia?

Tags: julia

Suppose I have a matrix named `mat`:

```
julia> mat = rand(1:10, 5, 3)
5×3 Matrix{Int64}:
 2  4   3
 5  3  10
 5  7   5
 9  5   7
 4  9   6
```

And I want to calculate the correlation between each pair of `mat` rows (e.g., `cor(mat[1, :], mat[2, :]` and so on), and finally, achieve a correlation matrix. I wrote two scripts for it, and I'll provide the benchmarking. However, I would be more pleased if I could make it much faster (because I should perform the procedure on a large dataset, say 2000x20 size).

## First approach

A pretty straightforward way; First, I create an initialized matrix with `zeros` and then try to fill it with the calculated correlations on each pair of rows. This isn't a good approach since I calculate twice as necessary (because, e.g., `cor([mat[1, :], mat[3, :])` is equal to `cor([mat[3, :], mat[1, :])`):

```
using Statistics

function calc_corr(matrix::Matrix)
    n::Int64 = size(matrix, 1)
    corr_mat = zeros(Float64, n, n)

    for (idx1, idx2)=Iterators.product(1:n, 1:n)
        @inbounds corr_mat[idx1, idx2] = cor(
            view(matrix, idx1, :),
            view(matrix, idx2, :)
        )
    end

    return corr_mat
end
```

## Second approach

Calculate the upper triangular part and then create a symmetrical matrix to achieve a complete correlation matrix:

```
using LinearAlgebra

function calc_corr2(matrix::Matrix)
    n::Int64 = size(matrix, 1)
    corr_mat = ones(Float64, n, n)

    # find upper triangular indices
    upper_triang_idx = findall(==(1), triu(ones(Int8, n, n), 1))

    for (idx1, idx2)=Tuple.(upper_triang_idx)
        @inbounds corr_mat[idx1, idx2] = cor(
            view(matrix, idx1, :),
            view(matrix, idx2, :)
        )
    end

    corr_mat = Symmetric(corr_mat)
    return corr_mat
end
```

## Benchmarking

1. First on a tiny matrix I declared before (the `mat`):

```
using BenchmarkTools

@benchmark calc_corr($mat)
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 10000 samples with 10 evaluations.
 Range (min … max):  1.950 μs …   6.210 μs  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% … 0.00%
 Time  (median):     2.160 μs               ┊ GC (median):    0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   2.178 μs ± 289.600 ns  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  0.00% ± 0.00%

  ▇▇▂ ▁ ▅█▆▂▁▁▃▆▅▃▁ ▁▁▁▁                                      ▂
  ███████████████████████▆█▇▇█▇▇▆▇▆▇▆▆▄▆▄▄▅▃▁▄▄▄▃▅▃▄▄▄▁▁▁▃▄▁▄ █
  1.95 μs      Histogram: log(frequency) by time      3.62 μs <

 Memory estimate: 256 bytes, allocs estimate: 1.

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------

@benchmark calc_corr2($mat)
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 10000 samples with 10 evaluations.
 Range (min … max):  1.220 μs … 773.080 μs  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% … 99.19%
 Time  (median):     1.420 μs               ┊ GC (median):    0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   1.698 μs ±   9.921 μs  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  8.15% ±  1.40%

  █          
  █▇▃▂▃▄▂▂▄▄▃▂▃▃▂▂▂▂▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁ ▁
  1.22 μs         Histogram: frequency by time        3.98 μs <

 Memory estimate: 976 bytes, allocs estimate: 7.
```

Test if the results are identical:

```
julia> calc_corr(mat) == calc_corr2(mat)
true
```

2. On a big matrix:

```
test_mat = rand(1:10, 2_000, 20);

@benchmark calc_corr($test_mat)
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 8 samples with 1 evaluation.
 Range (min … max):  632.258 ms … 680.094 ms  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.33% … 1.30%
 Time  (median):     646.215 ms               ┊ GC (median):    0.16%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   650.096 ms ±  16.089 ms  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  0.49% ± 0.60%

  ▁ ▁           ▁  █       ▁                 ▁                ▁  
  █▁█▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁█▁▁█▁▁▁▁▁▁▁█▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁█▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁█ ▁
  632 ms           Histogram: frequency by time          680 ms <

 Memory estimate: 30.52 MiB, allocs estimate: 2.

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------

@benchmark calc_corr2($test_mat)
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 14 samples with 1 evaluation.
 Range (min … max):  351.040 ms … 396.431 ms  ┊ GC (min … max): 2.58% … 1.81%
 Time  (median):     357.403 ms               ┊ GC (median):    2.86%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   360.863 ms ±  11.661 ms  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  2.75% ± 0.80%

    █           
  ▇▁█▇▁▇▇▁▁▁▇▁▁▁▇▇▁▇▁▁▇▁▇▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▇ ▁
  351 ms           Histogram: frequency by time          396 ms <

 Memory estimate: 99.63 MiB, allocs estimate: 14.
```

Memory isn't my main concern for now, and I'm looking for a way to make this procedure faster and optimal. The speed would be annoying if you create a more giant matrix like 10_000x100 (So the memory ). Hence, I'm looking for any advice that helps me to achieve a higher speed for this procedure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not reinvent the wheel, just do

```
cor(test_mat, dims=2)
```

This is much faster than your code.

Setup:

```
test_mat = rand(1:10, 2_000, 20)
```

And now benchmark:

```
julia> @btime calc_corr2($test_mat);
  709.354 ms (16 allocations: 99.63 MiB)

julia> @btime cor(test_mat, dims=2);
  52.679 ms (16 allocations: 30.85 MiB)
```

Comment: I shall delete my account. I didn't know that `cor` can do it 

Comment: do not worry we are all learning all the time!

Comment: *"your code makes bad assumption on transposition the data"* I didn't get your point. Can you explain more please?

Comment: There should be a correction, I guess. Because `test_mat2 = rand(1:10, 10_000, 100);` and then `cor(test_mat2)` would result in a 100x100 matrix. I guess we should do `cor(test_mat2')`. Am I true?

Comment: `calc_corr2(test_mat)` in my example results in 2000x2000 matrix - see the code in my answer.

Comment: @Przemysław I think @Shanyan wanted correlation between rows, so one should write `cor(mat, dims=2)`. Your code computes correlation between columns (this is the default).

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński exactly! As I stated in question *" I want to calculate the correlation between each pair of mat rows"*.

Comment: Off-question comment: `cor` calculates `mean` in order to get at Pearson correlation, wouldn't it be nice to expose the `mean` to user, as this is often a useful output. Maybe a returned struct (like `qr()` etc.)

Comment: OK I was so much used to going always over columns that did not read `rows` - answer updated

Comment: @Dan Getz - the current design is opposite. It assumes you can pre-calculate mean and then use the `corm` function by passing a mean to it to avoid re-computation.

Comment: Wouldn't transposing your matrix so it fits to cor would be a wise path?